# Fast prefix match

Tags: php

I need to match a certain number of prefixes for a list of strings, and gather only the strings that have one of those prefixes, like this:

```
$prefixes = array('Dr.', 'Prof.', 'Atty.', 'Rev.');

$results = array();

foreach($names as $name){

  $this_prefix = false;

  foreach($prefixes as $prefix){
    if(strpos($name, $prefix) === 0){
      $this_prefix = $prefix;
    }
  }

  if($this_prefix !== false){
    $name = substr($name, strlen($prefix) + 1);
    $results[$this_prefix][] = $name;
  }

}
```

The code above does the job, but is there any faster solution?

Comment: You could add a `break;` after `$this_prefix = $prefix;`, but that won't speed it up too much.

Comment: You could use `preg_match` for this with pattern: `#^(Dr\.|Prof\.|Atty\.|Rev\.).*#`

Comment: thanks Bartosz your regex works; the time seems to be almost the same as with my code, but if I add `S` before # like Basti said below it drops to half, which is much faster :D

Comment: why remove the "string" tag? :o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a regular expression match, those are really fast using the pre-compiled preg_match function, an expression may be like:
 `/(Dr\\.|Prof\\.|Atty\\.|Rev\\.)/`

Run that through preg_match and your result will be in the matches array. I think that's what you're looking for?

Comment: and maybe use the modifier S, to account for the reuse of the pattern.

Comment: @Basti nice point, but anyway I think that `preg_` functions will always have worse performance than using `strncmp` and one loop (basically those are 4+20 `INC`s and ~20 `CMP`s if written in C... and PCRE requires complex evaluation...)

Comment: i would be so sure about this. as u said in your answer strcmp would do the work in O(n) time where n is the length of the prefix. that is O(p*n) for the whole problem where p is the number of prefixes and n the avg length of a prefix. using a DFA (regular expression) you can match all prefixes in O(max(n_i)) where max(n_i) is the longest prefix. the construction of the DFA is neglect able (== i don't remember the complexity ;) ). in the end it doesn't really matter. both ways will suffice.

Comment: @Basti can you provide some reference for `O(max(n_i))`? I'm lazy to look up article on my own right now.

Comment: sorry i thought about this myself. consider a DFA that has a state for every char in a prefix and a path for every prefix. to decide if a string matches you would have to follow just one path. if the string matches, the DFA has gone though the whole path. if not it has passed the whole path or less, but not more. the worst case is that the string contains the longest prefix without the prefix' last character. the DFA will now have to go along the longest path to decide if it matches.

Answer (score 3):

The function that was designed for such comparisons is [`strncmp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strncmp.php), it does job in `O(n)` time (where n is length of prefix). Example:

```
$prefixes = array('Dr.', 'Prof.', 'Atty.', 'Rev.');

$results = array();

foreach($names as $name){

  $this_prefix = false;

  foreach($prefixes as $prefix){
    if(strncmp($name, $prefix, strlen( $prefix)) == 0){
      $this_prefix = $prefix;
      break;
    }
  }

  if($this_prefix === false){
    continue;
  }

  $name = substr($name, strlen($prefix) + 1);
  $results[$this_prefix][] = $name;

}
```

And add [`break`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) statement so it'll stop after first match. If you don't need to do anything when you won't match prefix you may use [`continue`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) (according to [Kernel Coding Style](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle) using more than 3 indentation is screw up so I preffer using continue instead of building large blocks inside if/else)

#### Edit

After doing a little research (thanks to the lolcat's comment) it looks like the possible solutions are following (ordered by performance, best first):

- `strpos()`
- `strncmp()`
- `substr() == $prefix`
- `preg_match()`

Source: http://maettig.com/code/php/php-performance-benchmarks.php, part called: *Check if a String starts with another String*.

Comment: this is actually slower than using strpos, try it :)

Comment: @thelolcat thanks man, I'm actually quite surprised to find this out... `strncmp` should really be composed of 15-20 ASM instructions and should works as hell :), anyway did some research and updated my answer

Comment: @thelolcat anyway I still believe that the slowest part is accessing each character with `strncmp` and the method is memory friendly. It's that straight forward method that it just can't get any better or more effective... + half of the time is taken for `strlen()` parameter (and so far I thought that php has string length cached but this seems like a NULL terminated thing).